# Problem with the "sudo apt-get update" command

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, software-sources

I'm a beginner when it comes to the Linux environment. I recently tried to install some extensions in Linux. I've entered some commands like:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

and then when I tried to update with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I received this message:

```
E: Type 'ME' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-team-gnome3-precise.list
```

Each time when I want to update I receive this error. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I may correct this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should edit gnome3-team-gnome3-precise.list with administrative privileges and manually remove all references to 'ME'. You can edit this file by opening terminal (shift+ctrl+T) and pasting the following commands (replace gedit with any text editor):

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-team-gnome3-precise.list
```

---

**Sources :**[[SOLVED] Cant update packages due to error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1737917)

Answer (score 0):

Try simply opening **Ubuntu Software Center** and see if it offers you to repair repositories.

If it doesn't solve the problem, open **Software Sources** find the offending one (probably a PPA you have added) and disable it.

Then try `sudo apt-get update` again.